# Recursion - Displaying wrong number of attempts

Tags: java, recursion, passwords

So the code is working fine however the number of attempts it takes to crack the 5 letter password is incorrect. I've tried fixing things however it's always giving me 3 digits. The number of attempts should be much higher.
Here's my code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Letters for the random generated password
        // Variables
        String letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
        Random order = new Random();
        int PASSWORD = letters.length();
        // While statement to allow user to keep generating passwords
        while (true) {
            String password = "";
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            // Print/menu
            System.out.println("Press 1 to generate a random password");
            // Takes user input
            int UserOption = input.nextInt();

            // If user input equals 1
            if (UserOption == 1) {
                // Generate a 5-character passwords from the letters in the String
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    password = password + letters.charAt(order.nextInt(PASSWORD));
                }
                System.out.println(password);
                cracking(5, password, letters, 0, "");
            }
            // If user input is anything except 1
            else {
                // Print error
                System.out.println("Error");
            }
        }
    }

    //Method for cracking password
    private static int cracking(int length, String password, String characters, int tries, String tryPass) {
        System.out.println(length);
        if (length == 0) {
            System.out.println("It took " +  tries + " tries to crack the password");
            return 0;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < characters.length(); i++) {
            if (password.charAt(length-1) == characters.charAt(i)) {
                tryPass = tryPass + characters.charAt(i);
                break;
            }
            tries++;
        }
        cracking((length-1), password, characters, tries, tryPass);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The length of the character set you are using is 62. The last character in the `letters` is `0`, so the number of tries that would be required to match `0` is `61` tries.

So even if the randomly generated 5 letter password contains `00000` (all are the last characters in your character set.), the total number of tries would be `61*5`, which is `305`. So the output would never be greater than this value.

Hence, this code would never return a value much higher than a 3-digit number. (I am assuming that you expected 4 or 5 digit numbers). Also, the maximum value it could return is `305`.

If you need the number of tries to be higher, then increase the password length.

Comment: That makes sense but in this case, wouldn't it be like for each letter it would take at max 62 tries, and for 5 letters it would be 62^5 total combinations? What changes would I need to make so that it includes every possible combination till it cracks the password?

Comment: @UO23 Yes there are 62^5 combinations. But for each position, it takes a maximum of 62 tries to find the correct character. So the maximum number of tries would be = `max tries per letter * number of letters` which is 62*5 ( In the current code, the `tries` is not incremented when character is matching, so max tries would be 61*5). Could you please explain why you need to check every possible combination (in lexicographic order?) to crack the password? Because, that approach would decrease the performance and has no other benefit.

Comment: @UO23 If the answer could be found in 62*5 steps or 62^5 steps then go for the 62*5 steps solution.